# Optionlist built in Ajax returns null value

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im new to javascript. Im using Ajax to request endpoint information. Im dynamically building my optionlist based on results form the endpoint but I cannot get the select to work.

I want to get the value from the option list based on the value of the option but I only get ”TypeError: elSelectArtist is null”

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var eId;
xhr.onload = function() {
    responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    // build dropdown
    var artistName = '';
    artistName += '<form name="jump" id="formArtist" class="center">' +
        '<select id="artistList" name="menu">' +
        '<option value="#">Choose Artist:</option>';

    for (var i = 0; i < responseObject.length; i++) {
        artistName += '<option value="'+ responseObject[i].id +'">' + responseObject[i].name + ' ';
        artistName += ' ' + responseObject[i].surname + '</option>';
    }
    artistName += '</select></form></p>';

    var elSelectArtist = document.getElementById('artistList');

    elSelectArtist.addEventListener('change', function() {
        alert(this.value);
        eId = this.value;
    }, false);

    document.getElementById('artists').innerHTML = artistName;
};

xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/api/artists', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

I did expect to get the value from the option list.

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
Vilken artist:
<script src="js/artists.js"></script>

List of artists:
<div id="artists"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `id="artistList"` doesn't exist in the HTML, maybe you misspelled it

Comment: need your html code

Comment: When you call, var elSelectArtist = document.getElementById('artistList'); that content is not set with document.getElementById('artists').innerHTML = artistName; code. so you need to call this before that.

Comment: artistList do exist as the select id

Comment: …which is just a string, not an HTML element…

Comment: okey, makes sense. so how can I grab the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var eId;
xhr.onload = function() {
    responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    // build dropdown
    var artistName = '';
    artistName += '<form name="jump" id="formArtist" class="center">' +
        '<select id="artistList" name="menu">' +
        '<option value="#">Choose Artist:</option>';

    for (var i = 0; i < responseObject.length; i++) {
        artistName += '<option value="'+ responseObject[i].id +'">' + responseObject[i].name + ' ';
        artistName += ' ' + responseObject[i].surname + '</option>';
    }
    artistName += '</select></form></p>';

    document.getElementById('artists').innerHTML = artistName; //changed position of this
    var elSelectArtist = document.getElementById('artistList'); //and this
    elSelectArtist.addEventListener('change', function() {
        alert(this.value);
        eId = this.value;
    }, false);        
};

xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/api/artists', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Your `id="artistList"` was still just a variable, if you add it to the DOM first, then reference it, then it works.